# How to convert UTC to local time

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, utc

I have to develop an application for ePrescribe and need to convert an UTC Time value (for example '2010-01-01T16:09:04.5Z') to local time. Delphi 2010, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the string manually first. Extract the individual values from it, then you can put them into a Win32 `SYSTEMTIME` record and call [`SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949.aspx) to convert it from UTC to local. You can then use the converted `SYSTEMTIME` however you need, such as converting it to a `TDateTime` using [`SystemTimeToDateTime()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.SysUtils.SystemTimeToDateTime).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TXSDateTime` class from unit `XSBuiltIns`

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  XSBuiltIns;

var xsDateTime: TXSDateTime;
    input, output:  string;
    date: TDateTime;

begin
  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    input := '2010-01-01T16:09:04.5Z';
    xsDateTime := TXSDateTime.Create;
    xsDateTime.XSToNative(input);
    date := xsDateTime.AsDateTime;
    output := 'Parsed date/time: ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss', date);
    writeln(output);
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Output:

```
Parsed date/time: 2010-01-01 19:09:04
```

Answer (score 0):

Your computer provides your time zone. You can use them to manipulate UTC time to adjust by adding hours and minutes.

Comment: I receive the UTC time as a string value, how to convert it?