# How to convert GMT datetime string to local datetime delphi

Tags: delphi, datetime

I received a string in the format "Mon, 17 Nov 2014 13:50:14 GMT" I need to convert into a TDateTime type to be able to work as I do that?

Comment: Parse the string, convert to a date time, convert from UTC to local. Which part are you stuck on, bearing in mind that this question has been asked here many many times. Did you do a websearch? Perhaps you need to search harder.

Comment: I searched yes, here and in google, the closest I found was the example "[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951273/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time)" but to inform my string error "**EXSDateTimeException: Invalid time string: Mon, 17 Nov 2014 13:50:14 GM**" thank you anyway.

Comment: That string is really really easy to parse. Split it on command and white space, and deal with each part. Do you know how to split strings? Do you know how to convert a string to an integer? Do you know how to convert from UTC to local? It looks like you aren't trying very hard, and want us to do it for you. Can't you show some willing? Have you really given up without making any attempt? Prove my doubts wrong please.

Comment: Sorry for the type, "command" -> "comma and". And the code you tried is for a different date format. Don't just try stuff at random. Think about it. Understand the problem. Understand any code you write. Trial and error is not a recognised development technique. Sorry to be so harsh, but there it is.

Comment: For me there could be some native function that would do it, I do not want anyone to do anything for me, even more so thank you for your criticism, I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: If you'd asked that it would have been a reasonable question. You could edit it to that form.

Comment: Have a look at Indy's `GMTToLocalDateTime` in `IdGlobalProtocols` unit.